# Calculate the principal part of $\pi\cot(\pi z)$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits, laurent-series

I calculated the principal part of $\pi\cot(\pi z)$ in $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ as $\dfrac1{z-n}$. Is this right?

Comment: So you claim $\pi\cot(\pi z) - \frac{1}{z-n}$ has a removable singularity at $z=n$.  Can you compute the limit there?

Comment: Yes, it is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your result is right. One has, for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, as $z \to n$,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{z \to n}(z-n)\cdot \pi\cot(\pi z)&=\lim_{z \to n}\left((z-n)\cdot \pi\frac{\cos(\pi z)}{\sin(\pi z)}\right)
\\\\&=\lim_{z \to n}\left((z-n)\cdot \pi\frac{\cos(\pi(z-n)+\pi n)}{\sin(\pi (z-n)+\pi n)}\right)
\\\\&=\lim_{z \to n}\left((z-n)\cdot \pi\frac{(-1)^n\cos(\pi(z-n))}{(-1)^n\sin(\pi (z-n))}\right)
\\\\&=\lim_{z \to n}\left(\frac{\pi (z-n)}{\sin(\pi (z-n))}\cdot\cos(\pi(z-n))\right)
\\\\&=1\cdot1
\\\\&=1.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Don't know why you got a down vote. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @N.Sch You are welcome.